# Mysql Order by Starting letter

Tags: mysql

I need to sort[order by] the query based on starting letter.

Ex.,
      there will be a title column.

I need to sort based on letter 'e'.

The result needed is , the fields starting with letter 'e' should come first and the rest of the result should come afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEFT(title, 1) = 'e' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
            title
```

Comment: @sathish Glad to help. Please mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking on the outlined check mark next to it.

Comment: Hi joe, Now i need to sort based on specified order ie., letters starting with 'e' should be first, then 'r' , then 's' ...   Can u help me...

Comment: @sathish: Just continue to extend the CASE statement as needed. `...ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEFT(title,1) = 'e' THEN 1 WHEN LEFT(title,1) = 'r' THEN 2 WHEN LEFT(title,1) = 's' THEN 3 ELSE 999 END, title`

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY (SUBSTR(LOWER(title), 1, 1)='e')
```

Comment: Your solution is not complete, you should sort the result by ASC or DESC at the end.

Comment: That requirement is not in the question. "The rest of the result" does not imply whether it should be sorted or not.

Comment: But the fields starting with letter 'e' didn't appear first without sorting.